# Security scan flagged local variable for heap inspection in C Function

Tags: c, heap-memory, static-analysis, checkmarx

I'm working on a C function `getCredentials` and encountered a Checkmarx flag regarding the variable `lpass`. However, in my understanding, both `lid` and `lpass` are locally stored on the stack within the function

```
void getCredentials(char *id, char *pass) {
    char lid[userid_size];
    char lpass[pwd_size]; // Flagged in Checkmarx 

    strncpy(lid, id, userid_size);
    strncpy(lpass, pass, pwd_size);

    // dbconnect(&dbstruct, lpass, lid);
}
```

Can someone clarify why Checkmarx flags `lpass` for heap inspection, and is this a false positive or if there's a potential issue that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Maybe OT: your usage of `strncpy` is probably wrong. Read very closely the documentation of `strncmp`, it is not the safer version of `strcpy`.

Comment: Buffer overflows can happen here, too. Remember the NUL terminator, and remember to **check error codes** from functions that can fail.

Comment: I am specifically concerned about heap inspection vulnerability, all the strncpy functions have been flagged for buffer_overflow

Comment: Why even bother to make a copy if all you do is pass the values to `dbconnect()`?

Comment: If `pwd_size` is variable, then the array is variable sized, and the implementation could choose to allocate it on the heap (probably not, but you can't say 100%). Maybe that's it?

Comment: Please present the exact diagnostic message emitted by Checkmarx.

Comment: Is the heap inspection vulnerability flagged before or after the `strncpy()` functions? If it is flagged after, it may be a false positive triggered by the `strncpy()` functions. If it is flagged before, it is probably not a false positive triggered by the `strncpy()` functions. Whether it's still a false positive depends on what Checkmarx means by 'heap inspection vulnerability'. It would be worth fixing the `strncpy()` problems and retesting. Why copy what is passed to the connect function? Why not ensure that the strings are null-terminated? Is there still a problem without `strncpy()`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there's a bunch of logic that happens before the string gets passed to dbconnect. I left out those lines since they seemed unrelated to heap inspection

Answer (score 2):

"Heap Inspection" is about sensitive information stored in the machine memory unencrypted. Where exactly it is stored is completely irrelevant.

Any copy of sensitive information should be destroyed as soon as it is no longer needed. Otherwise an attacker who has read-only access to the process memory can inspect it and search for sensitive data. <s>it can potentially survive deallocation, death of the process, and subsequent allocation of that memory by a different process, where it can be inspected.</s>

If you need to temporarily store an unencrypted copy of a password, zero it out as soon as you are done with it. This mitigates the risk, not eliminates it completely. The latter is not possible under this model of attack, because the breach has already occurred and the attacker has some level of access. If he is sufficiently lucky, he will find unencrypted info just in the brief moment when it exists.

Comment: This is not really my area of expertise. Caveat emptor.

Comment: Since this exploit only occur if the machine is already compromised, and the application runs on a private server. Considering the complexity of the fix, low issue severity, and the fact that it wouldn't prevent the initial compromise, dismissing this seems reasonable.